# Adjust dates form in excel output pandas package

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that extracts data from pdf file and the code is working well. As for the column G in the excel file has dates but when trying to change the dates format in the excel file, the format doesn't respond. I have to double click each cell to get the desired format

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd

def extract_lines(pdf_file_path, excel_output_path):
    table_data = []
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file_path) as pdf:
        for page_number in range(len(pdf.pages)):
            page = pdf.pages[page_number]
            page_text = page.extract_text()
            rows = page_text.strip().split('\n')
            for row in rows:
                if row.strip()[-1].isdigit():
                    segments = row.strip().split()
                    table_data.append(segments)
    if table_data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
        df = df.iloc[:, ::-1]
        excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_output_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(excel_writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        workbook = excel_writer.book
        worksheet = excel_writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        worksheet.right_to_left()
        excel_writer._save()
        print(f'PDF Data Converted And Saved To {excel_output_path}')
    else:
        print('No Lines Ending With Digits Found In The PDF')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extract_lines('Sample.pdf', 'Output.xlsx')
```

I tried to apply the format `strftime("%d/%m/%Y")` in the code but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

From the pandas.ExcelWriter documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

```
Parameters:
    date_format : str, default None
        Format string for dates written into Excel files (e.g. ‘YYYY-MM-DD’).
```

So you want

```
pd.ExcelWriter(excel_output_path, engine='xlsxwriter', date_format='DD-MM-YYY')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I got an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 31, in <module>
    extract_lines('Sample.pdf', 'Output.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 19, in extract_lines
    excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_output_path, engine='xlsxwriter', date_formatstr='DD-MM-YYY')
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ExcelWriter.__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_formatstr'
`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my cut-and-paste.  The "str" was not supposed to be there.  I think I have fixed things now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is that the column of dates is considered as text and when I used excel to change the format, the dates are the same. only if I double click in a cell, the date is changed correctly.

Comment: In Excel you should be able to select the column and get to Format Cells from either the menu bar or the right click context menu and select the date format you want to change the column to a "real" date column.

Comment: yes, I did that but the format doesn't change. only changed if I double click into a cell

Comment: Ah.  Perhaps the issue is that you need to tell the DataFrame that the columns represent dates.  After your DataFrame creation try adding `df.astype({'your-date-column-name': 'datetime64[ns]'})`.  Maybe then it will create the Excel file knowing that the column represents a date.

Comment: this line works fine ``df.iloc[:, 6] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 6])`` but I got the format of the date as date and time and I need date only. But this solved the problem of the dates format.

Comment: this line solved the problem ``df.iloc[:, 6] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 6]).dt.date``